# Algorithm to compose identity from a set of permutations

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, combinatorics, permutations

Given a subset P of all the possible permutations of a fixed set of elements, is there a non-exponential or optimized algorithm for computing the smallest composition of P that yields the identity permutation?

Comment: This is closely related to the [word problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups) for finite groups, except that you're not restricting your set of permutations to be a group and you're looking for the shortest word equivalent to the identity. (Note that there are infinite groups with finite descriptions whose word problem is undecidable but I guess you're only dealing with finite sets of permutations.)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that "smallest composition" means smallest number of permutations used in the composition, then the NP-complete [Pancake Flipping Problem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.0434) is a special case of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal{PRODUCT-PARTITION}$ is strongly $\mathrm{NP}$-hard as shown by [Ng et al.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221710003905)

If you allow the representation of a permutation over $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_p$ to be almost-unary: except for one permutation, every other is given by the multiplier $a\in\mathbb{Z}^{*}_p$ in unary. And lastly, $p$ itself is given in binary. The only one other permutation is given by its multiplier $A\in\mathbb{Z}^{*}_p$ in binary, then your problem is $\mathrm{NP}$-hard.

Now, we show that $\mathcal{PRODUCT-PARTITION}$ can be reduced to our problem $\mathcal{PERM-IDENTITY}$.

**Theorem**: $\mathcal{PRODUCT-PARTITION}\leq_p\mathcal{PERM-IDENTITY}$

**Proof**: Given an instance $\{a_1,\:a_2,\:\dots,\: a_n\}$ of $\mathcal{PRODUCT-PARTITION}$, we show how to construct an instance of $\mathcal{PERM-IDENTITY}$.

Since all the $a_i$'s are given in unary (thanks to strong hardness), we are able to, in polynomial time, construct a prime $q$ (in unary) that is bigger any prime divisor of all the $a_i$'s. By $\Pi$, we denote the product of all the $a_i$'s. We can assume $\Pi$ to be a square number and that no $a_i$ is equal to $1$. Taking the modulus to be some big enough $k$th power of $q$ such that $p=q^k>\Pi$. All the following is done modulo $p$.

Now, we transform each $a_i$ to a permutation $\pi_i$ over $\{0, 1, \dots, p-1\}$ that describes the operation of multiplying with $a_i$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Now, the produced instance of our problem is $\{\pi_1, \:\pi_2, \:\dots, \:\pi_n,\:sqrt(\Pi)^{-1}\}$ (modulo $p$) (actually, the last one should be the corresponding permutation of $sqrt(\Pi)^{-1}$, but abusing the notation a little bit may not be quite harmful here).

If the given $\mathcal{PRODUCT-PARTITION}$ instance is a $\mathrm{YES}$ instance, then by taking the set of permutations corresponding to the set of numbers in the solution to the $\mathcal{PRODUCT-PARTITION}$ instance and $sqrt(\Pi)^{-1}$, we can easily see that the produced instance is a $\mathrm{YES}$ instance of $\mathcal{PERM-IDENTITY}$.

Conversely, if the produced instance of $\mathcal{PERM-IDENTITY}$ is a $\mathrm{YES}$ instance, then note that the product of any subset of the $n$ permutations corresponding to $a_i$ is quite small to $p$ (in the magnitude of their corresponding natural numbers). So, in order for the product to be $1\:\mathrm{mod}\:p$, the last permutation corresponding to $sqrt(\Pi)^{-1}$ (which is somehow bigger than the $a_i$'s) must be taken. Then, the set of $a_i$'s corresponding to the rest of the solution to the produced instance of $\mathcal{PERM-IDENTITY}$ problem must multiply up to exactly $sqrt(\Pi)$ (which is somehow similar in magnitude to the $a_i$'s). Thus, the given $\mathcal{PRODUCT-PARTITION}$ instance is a $\mathrm{YES}$ instance.$\square$

Comment: What is *PRODUCT-PARTITION*?

Comment: Also, it's $\mathcal{REALLY\ HARD}$ to read all those script-font problem names. `\textsc{...}` (small caps) is much more legible.